# Leibniz rule of integration applied to Debye heat capacity

Tags: integration, physics

The quantity $C_V = \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial T}$ is called the heat capacity in physics, where $U$ is a function of temperature $T$ and other variables. For the case of the Debye's model of a solid, the function $U$ is an energy, and can be shown to be

$$U = 9Nk\frac{1}{T_D^3}\int_0^{x_D}\frac{x^3T^4}{e^x-1}dx,$$
where $N, k, T_D$ are constants and $x_D = \hbar\omega_D/(kT),$ where $\hbar,\omega_D$ are also constants. If I apply Leibniz integral rule I get that the derivative of the integral with respect to $T$ is

$$ \int_0^{x_D}\frac{4T^3 x^3}{e^x - 1}dx + \frac{T^4x_D^3}{e^{x_D}-1}\dfrac{\partial x_D}{\partial T}.$$

However, the result that is on the textbooks is
$$\int_0^{x_D}\frac{T^3x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}dx.$$

I am struggling in getting there, how can I reach the expected result? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both results are indeed consistent, it all comes down to an integration by parts,

Starting from the textbook result, we can integrate by parts,

$$\int_0^{x_D}\frac{T^3x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}dx = \frac{-x^4 T^3}{(e^x-1)}\Big|_0^{x_D}+\int_0^{x_D}\frac{4T^3 x^3}{e^x - 1}dx.$$

Now we rewrite the first term,

$$\frac{-x^4 T^3}{(e^x-1)}\Big|_0^{x_D} = \frac{-x_D^4 T^3}{(e^{x_D}-1)} = \frac{x_D^3 T^4}{(e^{x_D}-1)} \cdot \frac{-x_D}{T} = \frac{x_D^3 T^4}{(e^{x_D}-1)} \dfrac{\partial x_D}{\partial T}. $$

Then the first equation becomes,

$$\int_0^{x_D}\frac{T^3x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}dx = \frac{x_D^3 T^4}{(e^{x_D}-1)} \dfrac{\partial x_D}{\partial T} +\int_0^{x_D}\frac{4T^3 x^3}{e^x - 1}dx,$$

which is the desired result.